# How to echo selected in options list looping?

Tags: php, html, echo

I want to presist (=keep values if error on form) my values from a dropdown menu ,  this is what i started with  :

```
    ...
    $priorities = array('low','normal','high'); 
    ...
    <select name="priority" id="priority">
       <?php 
          foreach ($priorities as $pro){
            echo '<option value="'.$pro.'">'.$pro.'</option>'; 
          }
        ?>
    </select>
```

It does the job but does not presist.

Now i want to get to something like this :

```
   <select name="priority" id="priority">
       <?php 
          $tel = 0;
          foreach ($priorities as $pro){
             echo '<option value="'.$tel.'"'.htmlentities('<?php if (isset($_POST[\'priority\']) && (int) $_POST[\'priority\'] === tel) { echo \'selected="selected"\'; } ?>').' >'.$pro.'</option>'; 
             $tel++;
          }
       ?>
    </select>
```

But that of course gives an error.

Anyone has any suggestions thx

Comment: good job at formulating my question better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I often implement this:

```
<select name="priority" id="priority">
    <?php
    foreach ($priorities as $pro)
    {
        $selected = (isset($_POST['priorities']) && $pro == $_POST['priority']) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option value="' . $pro . '" '.$selected.'>' . $pro . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Just thought I'd point out you can actually shorten the [ternary](http://php.net/ternary) here like so

```
<select name="priority" id="priority">
    <?php
    foreach ($priorities as $pro)
    {
        $selected = ($pro == @$_POST['priority']) ? 'selected' : '';
        echo '<option value="' . $pro . '" '.$selected.'>' . $pro . '</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Sorry I've got a bit of a thing for creating the shortest code possible :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer you saved me a lot of time

Comment: No problem at all friend, thank you for a well presented first question :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the second part of the code to:

```
<select name="priority" id="priority">
   <?php 
      foreach ($priorities as $pro) {
         if (isset($_POST['priority']) && $_POST['priority'] == $pro) {
            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
         }
         else {
            $selected = null;
         }
         echo '<option value="'.$pro.'" '.$selected.'>'.$pro.'</option>'; 
      }
   ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select name="priority" id="priority">
   <?php 
      $tel = 0;
      foreach ($priorities as $pro){
         echo '<option value="' 
            .$tel
            .'"'
            .(isset($_POST['priority']) && (int)$_POST['priority'] === $tel)?'selected="selected"':''
            .' >'
            .$pro
            .'</option>'; 
         $tel++;
      }
   ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$priority= array (1=>"low","normal","high");
    $select = "<select name=\"priority\"> ;
      foreach ($priority as $key => $val) {
        $select .= "\t<option val=\"".$key."\"";
        if ($val == $yourcheckedvariable) {
           $select .= " selected=\"selected\">".$val."</option>\n";
        } else {
        $select .= ">".$val."</option>\n";
    }
}
 $select .= "</select>";
echo $select;
```

use this code